# Issues while using JAX to minimize the Lennard-Jones potential for two points and the force (gradient of the potential)--result doesn't match

Tags: python, machine-learning, optimization, minimization, jax

I am trying to use the minimization function in JAX to find the distance of two points satisfying Lennard-Jones potential E = 2(1/r^4-1/r^2) and I can succssfully get the result: [-0.20710678  1.20710678], which r = 1.41 as expected. However, next I define a function of force, which is the gradient of the lennard_jones potential and I am trying to minimize force^2, which the minimum is zero and should occurr at the same r value(1.41) as consistent with potential. However, I am getting really deviated result: [-4.77206934  5.77206934], where the r is 10 and it is obviously not right. I plot the function of force and it looks pretty smooth and not too sharp to me. so I am wondering where things go wrong.

Here is the code:

```
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax.scipy.optimize import minimize
from jax import vmap, grad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N =2
jax.config.update("jax_enable_x64", True)


x_init = jnp.arange(N, dtype=jnp.float64)
epsilon = 1
sigma = 1

def potential(r):
    r = jnp.where(r == 0, jnp.finfo(jnp.float64).eps, r)
    return 2 * epsilon * ((sigma/r)**4 - (sigma/r)**2)
def force(r):
    d_potential_dr = grad(potential)
    return (d_potential_dr(r)**2)
def F(x):
    # Compute all pairwise distances
    r = jnp.abs(x[:, None] - x[None, :])

    # Compute all pairwise potentials or force
    pot = vmap(vmap(force))(r)

    # Exclude the diagonal (distance = 0) and avoid double-counting by taking upper triangular part
    pot = jnp.triu(pot, 1)

    # Sum up all the potentials
    total = jnp.sum(pot)

    return total

# Minimize the function
result = minimize(F, x_init, method='BFGS')

# Extract the optimized positions of the points
x_solutions = result.x
print(x_solutions)
```

If I minimize regards to potential, where   `pot = vmap(vmap(potential))(r)`, I get result where the distance is 1.4(correct)

and if I minimize regards to force, where   `pot = vmap(vmap(force))(r)`, I get result where distance 10(obviously not right)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer here is essentially identical to the answer to your previous related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76353733/2937831

If you hold the position of the first point at zero, then plot the potential as a function of the second point, you see this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = jnp.linspace(0, 10, 100)
plt.semilogy(x, [F(jnp.array([0, xi])) for xi in x])
```

[image]

Note the log scale on the y-axis. This is a function that would be very difficult for any gradient-based optimizer to correctly minimize, because the gradient diverges to the left of the minimum, and trends toward zero to the right of the minimum. This case is probably even worse than the one in the original question, because the width of the region containing the minimum is so narrow.

If you want to minimize this sort of function, I'd look toward analytic or semi-analytic rather than numerical techniques. Gradient-based optimizers are not going to perform well with potentials of this form.

Comment: True. I agree with this and I need to think more about this. Thank you very much for your help!